# onclose and onerror not getting called on DataChannel disconnect

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a [wall application](//wholcomb.github.io/SimpleSignaling/) using WebRTC DataChannels. In [the code](//github.com/wholcomb/SimpleSignaling/blob/gh-pages/examples/wall.js) I've managed to work out the connection, but I'm not getting notified when a peer disconnects. On the channels I have the following listeners:

```
channels[uid].onerror = function( event ) {
  console.log( 'channels[uid].onerror', uid, arguments )
  removePeer( uid )
}

channels[uid].onclose = function() {
  console.log( 'channels[uid].onclose', uid, arguments )
  removePeer( uid )
}
```

When I reload tabs disconnecting peers, I don't get close messages. When I send to them, I don't get an error.

Answer (score 3):

It's currently due to incomplete implementation - the close event won't always fire for the data channel, unfortunately.

For Chrome:
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1676

Comment: Plus, on Firefox there's an "onclosedconnection" event fired for mozRTCPeerConnection objects.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar situation except 'onclose' inconsistently fires (working in FireFox). Sometimes it will work as expected and sometimes not. Seemingly randomly. @Makkes or anyone, do you have any possible explanation for this behavior?

Comment: @Xaxis: The behavior of implementations regarding 'close' events is a pain at the moment. Perhaps you're experiencing one of https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=881337 or https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1009124. If not, you could file a bug including steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Makkes: Right you are, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1009124 definitely seems to describe the bug that is at the heart of my issue. Plenty of google searches, and I didn't see that one. Thanks! Anyway, I suppose I'll keep developing as though that bug will be resolved in the near future.

Answer (score -1):

You have to renagotiate the peer connection to fire onclose datachannel.

your peer should exchange offer and answer, after any changes that you made on any peer to get everything work.

that means every time you made change you should renegotiate peerconnection.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer more